# How do i override conflicting 3rd party selectors in angular?

Tags: angular

My project currently has a module component that uses the selector 'ng-select'. The project has been abandoned by its maintainer, and i'd like to switch to using https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select.

I would like to use the components side by side until i can refactor the old library out.

Problem: There's a collision between selectors.

```
Error:(24, 5) Angular: More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: SelectComponent,NgSelectComponent
```

How do i rename the selector for the new library to be unique?

Comment: If you use this module, you have some source code, right ? can't you rename the selectors in the source files of the module ?

Comment: Put the components using the first one in NgModule A, and the components using the other in NgModule B. Make A import the old NgSelect module, and B import the new one.